# Advice and etiquette for building up collaborations

Tags: funding, job, tenure-track

I'm going to start a tenure-track position in fall. I'm planning to start some collaborations with some researchers that are a lot more senior than myself, who I met at some conferences and with whom I have joint interests.

When contacting them regarding a visit, should I straightaway offer to take care of the travel/accommodation costs or should I postpone that question for now?

Comment: This depends on the field. In some fields there is no need to physically meet in order to perform the collaboration, and some of these  senior scientists might in fact prefer not to visit at an early stage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You sound very optimistic that having met a senior colleague at a conference and having a desire to work with them, will automatically lead to a collaboration. You should consider that they may have other constraints on their time, and may not be able or interested to engage in more collaborations.

Before jumping into the details such as travel arrangements, you should first find out whether they are interested in a collaboration and, if the answer is yes, how they would like to go about it.